# What flower is this with long numerous white and purple petals?

Tags: identification, dahlias

Can someone please help me to identify this lovely flower.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There used to be a road side gazebo that had masses of these flowers for sale, you left the coin and choose your flowers.  Based on the 'honor' system!

This is a Dahlia. When you look them up you will be amazed at the variety, too perfect to be 'natural'?  Like Tulips grows from a bulb, unlike tulips, this bulb needs to be dug up every fall before the ground freezes, stored in a cool garage in sawdust and darkness. Plant again in the spring as soon as the soil warms up enough.  You might catch the Dahlia Fever.

Dahlia Tartan. I am sure there are better botanical names somewhere.  Dahlia's are very straightforward, they share a long history with the Tulip.  I own a book written about JUST the Tulip that is 2 1/2 inches thick.  Serious fortunes and lives lost over the Tulip, very dramatic.  I like the Dahlia much better!

I can't believe I found the same color as your flower.
[Purple with white tips Dahlia](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/01/91/8e/01918e619bda045aab7dbd2099cfb63b.jpg)
[Dinner Plate Purple Dahlia](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1419/7120/products/Dahlia_Thomas_Edison.IBULB.jpg?v=1516813949)

[Tartan Dinner Plate Dahlia](https://www.brecks.com/product/Tartan-Dinnerplate-Dahlia?p=0759874&msclkid=9e4d37d0dbe5102816736c347cb72535&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Bing%20Shopping%20Ads%20-%20Product%20Listing%20Ads&utm_term=1100100473478&utm_content=Home%20%26%20Garden%20%3E%20Plants%20%3E%20Flowers%20%3E%20Dahlia%20-Catalog#)